# How can I disable client validation for some fields in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

How can I disable client validation for some fields in asp.net MVC.
I have not defined any validation for Order property but it show "The Order field is required" in client. I want to disable client validation for Order.

```
   public class Product
    {
     ...
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name Is Required")]
     public String Name { get; set; }

     public int Order { get; set; }
     ...
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int` is `non nullable` type. Is cannot be assigned empty value, so metadata provider automatically makes it required. If your business doesn't need `Order` field filled in for `Product` class, make it nullable type - `Nullable<int> Order`. This way it won't be made required unless you explicitly make it.
Well, there is another way - using some scripts on client side. But this will disable validation only on client side, after post to server, the error message will still appear unless you make it `nullable`. Assuming you use default jquery validation plugin for asp.net mvc 3, you can use [remove rules function](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22remove.22rules)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I found around this is to use the ? character to set the value type (in this case int) to a nullable value type:

public int? Order { get; set; }